# What is the optimal buffer size to increase efficiency of the application?

Tags: c#, file-io, buffer, filestream, memorystream

I have an application which reads a file and copy's its content and writes into another file.
I am using buffer to read the file and write into another file.

The application take too long when the files are more.

Is there any specific optimal buffer size value that I can use to make the application more efficient?

I have used 256KB as maximum buffer size.

Below Upload method is called within a Parallel.ForEach loop.

Below is the code :

```
private bool Upload(string address, string uploadFile, string user, string password, string clientLogFile)
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server. 
        FtpWebRequest request = null;
        try
        {
            request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["timeout"]);

            request.UsePassive = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ftpMode"]);
            // _fileBufferSize = 256kb
            byte[] buffer = new byte[_fileBufferSize];
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(uploadFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                long dataLength = (long)fs.Length;
                long bytesRead = 0;
                int bytesDownloaded = 0;
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    while (bytesRead < dataLength)
                    {
                        bytesDownloaded = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        bytesRead = bytesRead + bytesDownloaded;
                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesDownloaded);
                    }
                    requestStream.Close();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Catch exception
        }
        finally
        {
            request = null;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You should post your question on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My first thought is that you do things serially... read, then write, then read, then write. I would change it so it reads and writes at the same time. So read buffer 1. Then at the same time read buffer 2 and write buffer 1. Then read buffer 3 while you write buffer 2.

Comment: Will the application be primarily used for files smaller, roughly the same size or larger than the current maximum buffer size?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Actually that Upload() method is called within a Parallel.ForEach loop. So, I think it is already doing the multitasking that you mentioned. Sorry for the incomplete question I will update it.

Comment: @Mast, files can vary and can be of size less or more than the specified buffer size.

Comment: And why do you think that buffer size is what makes it "slow"?

Comment: @Evk I am not sure if the problem is the buffer size. But, if there is an specific optimal size then it would really help me.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate your files to upload into multiple tasks to run, then execute several tasks in parallel.

Read [this older guide from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx) on parallel tasks. A modern version of this might look like this code below.

```
public void UploadAllFiles(IEnumerable<FileUploadParameters> files) {
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var file in files) {
        var task = Task.Run(() => {
            UploadFile(file);
        });

        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually that Upload() method is called within a Parallel.ForEach loop. So, I think it is already doing the multitasking that you mentioned. Sorry for the incomplete question I will update it.